# Implementing algorithms for Randomly generated array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, random

So I have the following code to generate an array comprised of random numbers from 1-20000 and the array can have different sizes (100, 500, 1000 etc).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


void insertSort(int input[]);
/*
void quickSort(int input[], int, int);
void mergeSort(int input[], int, int);
void merge(int input[], int, int, int);
void percolate(int numbers[], int, int);
void heapSort(int numbers[], int);
*/
int SIZE; //global Size variable


int main()
{
      int i;
      //int size;
      int random_once[10000]; //maximum array size

      srand(time(0));

      cout << "How big would you like the list to be?" << "\n\n";
      cout << "\t Enter any of the following: 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 8000, or 10000" << "\n";
      cin >> SIZE;

      for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
      {
          random_once[i]=rand() % 20000; //generating a random number between 1 - 20000

          // generate unique random number only once so no duplicates
          for(int j=0; j<i; j++) if (random_once[j]==random_once[i]) i--;

      }
      cout<< " " << i << "\n\n\n ";
      for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) cout << " " << random_once[i] << "\t";  //outputting array to console

  return 0;
}



//insert sort algorithm
void insertSort(int input[]) {
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        temp = input[i];
        for (j = i; j > 0 && temp < input[j - 1]; j--) {
            input[j] = input[j - 1];
        }
        input[j] = temp;
    }
    return;
}
```

I was wondering how I can have the insertion sort be printed out so that it prints out the sorted array after it used the insertion sort algorithm.

I was also wondering how I can print out the time complexity of the algorithm before being sorted and after so that I can compare it with other sorting algorithms.

**EDIT (with added template)**

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void insertSort(int input[]);
/*
void quickSort(int input[], int, int);
void mergeSort(int input[], int, int);
void merging(int input[], int, int, int);
void percolate(int numbers[], int, int);
void heapSort(int numbers[], int);
*/
int SIZE; //global Size variable


template <typename F, typename... Args>
std::string callTime(F func, int array[], Args... args) {
    using namespace chrono;
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    func(array, args...);
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    return to_string(duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count()) + "ms\n";
}

int main()
{

      int i;
      //int size;
      int random_once[10000]; //maximum array size

      srand(time(0));

      //asking user for the size of the list
      cout << "How big would you like the list to be?" << "\n\n";
      cout << "\t Enter any of the following: 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 8000, or 10000" << "\n";
      cin >> SIZE;

      //for loop to generate numbers and nested for loop to handle duplicates
      for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
      {
          random_once[i]=rand() % 20000; //generating a random number between 1 - 20000

          // generate unique random number only once so no duplicates
          for(int j=0; j<i; j++) if (random_once[j]==random_once[i]) i--;

      }//end generating for loop
      cout<< " " << i << "\n\n\n ";
      for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) cout << " " << random_once[i] << "\t";  //outputting array to console

      cout << "insertSort(): " << callTime(&insertSort, random_once);
  return 0;
} //end main




//insert sort algorithm
void insertSort(int input[]) {
 int i, j, temp;
 for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
  temp = input[i];
  for (j = i; j > 0 && temp < input[j - 1]; j--) {
   input[j] = input[j - 1];
  }
  input[j] = temp;
 }
}
```

Comment: There's no `getAlgorithmComplexity()` function. That's something you assert by looking at the code.

Comment: Is that only needed to get the time complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: use [clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) to save time before you run algorithm, get time after algorithm, difference between them is time it took. If I got what you are asking.

Comment: most sorting algorithms allow you to provide a custom comparator. Inside this comparator you can count how many times it gets called.

Comment: @MarekChocholáček So with that I can output the time complexity of the algorithms, and with how I have the insertSort algorithm setup it will automatically run it, it's just not outputting the sorted array. (Which I don't believe is needed) but the algorithm is working in the background correct?

Comment: @RileyKennedy I don't necessarily understand what are you trying to ask. However I can post an answer about how to print how much time it took to sort it (how many millisecond for example). If that's what you want.

Comment: @MarekChocholáček That would be awesome! I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There is no single "Time Complexity" of algorithms, in general. You can talk about bounds on the best, average, worst cases. Additionally you can measure the times taken for various runs on various input sizes, and use that to estimate the bounds, which your code seems to be doing

Comment: @RileyKennedy on it

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I get you right, but what you can do is to measure time before and after call of sorting functions. For time measurement C++ has various tools for example [std::high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) which I am using in code bellow. You can then observe how sorting algorithms behave on arrays of different sizes. There I wrote you template function which should be usable with every sort you plan to implement(don't forget to include chrono header):

```
#include <chrono>

template <typename F, typename... Args>
std::string callTime(F&& func, int array[], Args&&... args) {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    func(array, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::to_string(duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count()) + "ms\n";
}
```

You can call it like this :

```
int main() {
    // what you have before
    cout << "insertSort(): " << callTime(insertSort, random_once);
    //...
    cout << "merge(): " << callTime&merge, random_once, /* other params */);
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can change precision of duration cast:

```
duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count() // now returns microseconds passed
```

Comment: @RileyKennedy If you have any questions, feel free to ask

Comment: I'm assuming the function for the time just goes under my insert sort function?

Comment: I'm getting this error: 
|In function 'std::string callTime(F, int*, Args ...)':|
|32|error: there are no arguments to 'to_string' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'to_string' must be available
|In instantiation of 'std::string callTime(F, int*, Args ...) [with F = void (*)(int*); Args = {}; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]':|
|61|required from here|
|32|error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope|

Comment: I've added an edit to the original post on how the code looks now with the addition of what you gave me!

Comment: @RileyKennedy include string header. Also you are printing array before it is sorted. insertSort gets called within callTime function.

Comment: @RileyKennedy and delete  'using namespace std' in my function

Comment: still getting this error: |30|error: there are no arguments to 'to_string' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'to_string' must be available [-fpermissive]|

Comment: @RileyKennedy would you mind if I check into that later? It's quite late night. However the code works for me, so you can either investigate issue with to_string or just do the same thing differently. I will suggest edit how you can do it differently tho.